# How similar are the "faulty sentence" sections of the Chinese Gaokao 高考 exam and the HSK6?

Tags: chinese, hsk, proficiency-testing

I recently learned the Chinese [Gaokao 高考 exam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaokao) includes a 病句 ("faulty sentence") section.  This has piqued my interest as I prepare for the HSK6 which includes the [notoriously hard HSK6 语病 ("faulty wording") section](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/5358/2795).

**Question**: How similar are the "faulty sentence" sections of the Chinese Gaokao 高考 exam and the HSK6?

I feel like this question needs to be "out there" as I've been preparing madly for the HSK6, and wouldn't have ordinarily thought to look at the 高考 for practice.

Answer (score 0):

Gaokao's is usually much harder. Most faulty sentence in HSK are based on basic grammar, but Gaokao's is aim at certain meaning of some uncommon words (not common in daily using but common in Gaokao simulation test).
So the way to do these questions is the same, to memory.